# How to get parameters in class function with php class

Tags: php, class

In my project, I had defined a Datasource class in php.

I want to call function with class, so I had define static getRedis function in Datasource class.

Here is Datasource.php code:

```
<?php

 namespace common;

 class Datasource {

 public $config_name;  

 public $server_region;  


public function __construct() {}

public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {
    $this->config_name=$config_name;
    $this->server_region=$server_region
    return $this->config_name;
}
}
```

Now I want to call getRedis function and display instance1 in my html page;

Here is html code:

```
<?php 
include "o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource.php";

$redis_obj = common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');
echo $redis_obj;
?>
```

But it words fail. I can not get $redis_obj. it shows nothing.

Who can help me?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in your function. As Barmar wrote, you have to use self:: instead of $this

Comment: A static method doens't have a `$this` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using $this context in static method. If you made your class variables static it will work.

More info [Static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Your code:

```
<?php

 namespace common;

 class Datasource {

    public static $config_name;  

    public static $server_region;  

    public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {
        self::$config_name=$config_name;
        return self::$config_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to call a function from your class, it does not have to be static. Make you function in your class public and it does not need to be in a constructor.

This is in your class.

```
public function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {
    $this->config_name=$config_name;
    $this->server_region=$server_region;
    return $this->config_name;
}
```

In the file that you want to call you function.

```
$variable = new Datasource; 
$variable->getRedis(); //This will call your function
```